# How to redirect to another url using : owa_util.redirect_url?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an Apex 21.1.3 Page

In the page I have a Before-Header Process with the code :

```
owa_util.redirect_url('https://www.google.com');
apex_application.stop_apex_engine;
```

When I run the page, it doesn't redirect, it shows instead the text : **Location: https://www.google.com**

[image]

I have the exact same code in an 19.2 Apex Application and it works correctly.

Does anyone know how to solve that please ?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
apex_util.redirect_url (p_url => 'http://www.google.com/');
```

---

I mean, *only* this; you don't have to *stop* the engine, `REDIRECT_URL` will do it itself.